# "$" dollar character prefixing cookies names

Tags: c#, cookies

I have this function to retreive response cookies in a CookieContainer (this.cookies)

```
private void getCookies(string url)
{

  // request
  HttpWebRequest request = CreateWebRequestObject(url);
  request.CookieContainer = this.cookies;

  request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
  request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", " es-MX,es;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
  request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";



  request.Method = "GET";
  request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:10.0.2) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0.2";

  // response
  using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
  {
    foreach (Cookie c in response.Cookies)
    {
      this.cookies.Add(new Cookie(c.Name, c.Value, c.Path, c.Domain));


    }
  }
}
```

But, when I debug the request in Fiddler, I get this:

[image]

Why there is a "$" in cookies?

According [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a18ka3h2.aspx)

> public Cookie(    string name,    string value,   string path,    string
>   domain )
>
> **name**
>       Type: System.String
>       The name of a Cookie. The following characters must not be used inside name: equal sign, semicolon, comma, newline (\n), return (\r),
>   tab (\t), and space character. The dollar sign character **("$")** cannot
>   be the first character.

How can I remove this character?

Comment: Are things broken? Are you having problems?

Comment: I want to replace $Domain to Domain and so on

Comment: If you alter the received cookies are you able to correctly create a new request based on these cookies?

Comment: `...new Cookie(c.Name.Skip(1),...`  ?

Comment: the problem is that I do this: new Cookie("Domain",...) and I get  "$Domain" in Fiddlers

Comment: But isn't that part of the way the cookie is encoded? If you get the actual value without the dollar sign in your code, what's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The $ you see is not the *name* of the cookie; it is an *attribute* associated with a cookie.

[RFC 2109](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2109.txt) deals with HTTP state management; section 4.4 specifically deals with the dollar sign prefix. Hope that helps...

Comment: RFC-2109 was obsoleted by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2965 in the year 2000, which in turn was obsoleted by https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265 in 2011. Just so people know: This latest RFC does not mention attributes for the [Cookie header value syntax](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265#section-5.4), so using these $-prefixed attributes has been obsolete for nearly a decade now.